# Runtime error 1004 unable to get the match property when using two index/match

Tags: vba, excel

Trying to make the below code work, but unfortunately the second index/match throws an error. The code works if I remove the "count" variable from the second part (works fine in the first index/match), and refer to a single cell, no idea why.

Tried initing a new counter variable, part 2 still throws an error. Also, is there a better way to refer to cells in a range, in a for loop, instead of the ghetto solution I used?

Thanks!

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim count As Integer

Set sht = ActiveSheet
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

count = 2

    For Each i In Range("f2:f" & LastRow)
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            i.Value = .Index(Worksheets("Area").Range("c:c"), .Match(Range("E" & count), Worksheets("Area").Range("a:a")))
        End With
        count = count + 1
    Next

count = 2

    For Each i In Range("h2:h" & LastRow)
    i.Value = count
        With Application.WorksheetFunction
            i.Value = .Index(Worksheets("Park reason").Range("C:C"), .Match(Range("G" & count), Worksheets("Park reason").Range("A:A")))
        End With
        count = count + 1
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a match was not found. Test for a match not found first. If you use `Application.Match` you can use the error returned in a test to see if a match was found before attempting to get your `i.value`. Do the same for both Match attempts.

```
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    Dim test As Variant
    test = Application.Match(Range("E" & count), Worksheets("Area").Range("a:a"), 0)
    If Not IsError(test) Then
        i.Value = .Index(Worksheets("Area").Range("c:c"), test)
    End If
End With
```

I would probably re-write as:

```
With sht
    Dim test As Variant
    test = Application.Match(.Range("E" & count), Worksheets("Area").Range("A:A"), 0)
    If Not IsError(test) Then
        i.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Area").Range("C:C"), test)
    End If
End With
```

I would also look to work with smaller ranges than entire columns i.e. not "C:C" for example. Find the used range/last row and work up to that.

Fuller version:

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()

    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim count As Long
    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    With sht
        count = 2
        Dim i As Range, test As Variant
        For Each i In .Range("F2:F" & LastRow)
            test = Application.Match(.Range("E" & count), Worksheets("Area").Range("A:A"), 0)
            If Not IsError(test) Then
                i.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Area").Range("C:C"), test)
            End If
            count = count + 1
        Next
        count = 2
        Dim test2 As Variant
        For Each i In .Range("H2:H" & LastRow)
            test2 = Application.Match(.Range("G" & count), Worksheets("Park reason").Range("A:A"))
            If Not IsError(test2) Then
                i.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Park reason").Range("C:C"), test2)
            End If
            count = count + 1
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Rewrote the second index/match as below, getting error 13, type mismatch as an error on the i.value line.

Comment: Did you try the above full script?

Comment: Thanks, ran the revised code separately, worked perfectly, but when I copied it over to the full scrip got a compile error, duplicate declaration. Once I figure out what it is, the script will be perfect, thanks again for the help!

Comment: Hi, then you have made an error when copying. Did you have some code already in the module? If you copy exactly as above and ensure you do not have option explicit twice for example you should be fine. Does it highlight a line with this error? Which one?

Comment: Yeah, got some code already in, but decided to take the lazy way out, and just called the 'test' sub at the end of script, everything is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Full code btw, not sure why I got a duplication error when copied into the cleanup sub, but with the workaround it's working.

```
Sub Cleanup()

Dim sToday As String
sToday = Format(Date, "mm-dd-yyyy")

ActiveSheet.Copy Before:=Worksheets("Park Reason")
Rows("1:12").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("G:H").Select
Selection.UnMerge
Columns("H:H").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
Rows("1:1").Select
Range("A:I").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="Yes"
Columns("G:G").EntireColumn.AutoFit
Range("A:I").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=Array("1" _
    , "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "30", "40", "50", "51", "99"), Operator:= _
    xlFilterValues
Range("A:I").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
    *removed*), Operator:=xlFilterValues
Range("A:I").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:= _
    xlYes

For Each i In Range(Range("G2"), Range("G2").End(xlDown))
    If IsNumeric(i) Then
        i.Value = CDec(i.Value)
    End If
Next

For Each i In Range(Range("B2"), Range("B2").End(xlDown))
     If IsNumeric(i) Then
        i.Value = CDec(i.Value)
    End If
Next

Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.Delete ' Shift:=xlToLeft
Selection.Insert ' Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("F1").Value = "Area"
Columns("H:H").Insert
Range("H1").Value = "Parking Reason"
ActiveSheet.Name = sToday

test

End Sub

Sub test()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim count As Long
Set sht = ActiveSheet
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With sht
    count = 2
    Dim i As Range, test As Variant
    For Each i In .Range("F2:F" & LastRow)
        test = Application.Match(.Range("E" & count), Worksheets("Area").Range("A:A"), 0)
        If Not IsError(test) Then
            i.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Area").Range("C:C"), test)
        End If
        count = count + 1
    Next
    count = 2
    Dim test2 As Variant
    For Each i In .Range("H2:H" & LastRow)
        test2 = Application.Match(.Range("G" & count), Worksheets("Park reason").Range("A:A"))
        If Not IsError(test2) Then
            i.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(Worksheets("Park reason").Range("C:C"), test2)
        End If
        count = count + 1
    Next
End With
End Sub
```